# Multiple 101 responses when querying CosmosDB using Gremlin

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Trying to diagnose some odd behaviour from CosmosDB when querying using Gremlin:

I've got a Blazor site that is querying Cosmos.  It's regularly timing out, or taking a long time to pull back results from Cosmos.  I've reduced the code down to:

```
var gremlinServer = new GremlinServer(
    Hostname, 
    Port, 
    true, 
    $"/dbs/{Database}/colls/{Collection}", 
    AuthKey
);

using var gremlinClient = new GremlinClient(
    gremlinServer, 
    new GraphSON2Reader(), 
    new GraphSON2Writer(), 
    GremlinClient.GraphSON2MimeType
);

var query = $"g.V().has('itemid', '{PartitionKey}')";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

try
{
    var results = await gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<dynamic>(query);
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(result);
    }

    Logger.LogInformation(sb.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.LogError($"Error executing Gremlin query: {ex.Message}");
}
```

When checking App Insights to see what is going on behind the scenes, I noticed a number of long running requests/redirects which seem to be causing the issues:

[image]

When it's working correctly those 101 responses return in < 100ms and the query executes correctly.  However, fairly regularly they can take > 30 secs to run and the query times out.

In terms of the database, there is < 1000 records in it.  Running the query directly on the DB returns in < 1 sec.  I've disabled any other processes that interact with the DB, so it doesn't seem to be a rate-limit issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit to provide more details about your schema (including partition key and some sample data, expected results, etc). Right now, it's hard to tell what's happening based on just a bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this - somewhere else in the project the WebSockets.KeepAliveInterval and ConnectionPoolSettings had been set to a non-default value which was causing this behaviour.  Removing that stopped the long running 101 requests.